# Python: Invalid ELF header importing cython compiled library

Tags: python, cython, elf

My problem is the following. I'm working on `Ubuntu` and have a `cython` code which I compile using the following:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(
   ext_modules = cythonize("cython_accelerate.pyx"),
   include_dirs = [numpy.get_include()]
)
```

Compilation works fine. When I try to import the generated library (cython_accelerate.so) I get the following error:

> invalid ELF header.

If I do the exactly same procedure on Mac everything works perfectly: the only difference is that the library is generated with a different name (cython_accelerate.cpython-35m-darwin.so) but import works as expected without issues.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `file` say about the type of the generated `.so` file? Can binutils tools such as `nm` parse it successfully? What *exactly* is your local platform (architecture and OS)? We really need more details to diagnose this -- full steps to reproduce, ideally.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm working on Ubuntu

This is a rather meaningless statement. Probably you are using Ubuntu on `x86_64` system.

If so, your problem is most likely due to 32-bit vs. 64-bit mismatch: you are trying to import 32-bit `cython_accelerate.so` into 64-bit Python process, or vice versa.

To verify this is the cause, run

```
file `which python`
file /path/to/cython_accelerate.so
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I get the following:
file `which python` -> /usr/bin/python: symbolic link to `python2.7'

file cython_accelerate.so -> ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=4b36e56da7adbc0cda2411aa72d146f4fc7e9864, not stripped